# Import an FBX armature with weights into Blender

Tags: armature, import

I'm having difficulty importing the armatures of FBX files into Blender.

The mesh is incorrectly scaled and rotated, and the armature is shot. I found a post (https://darisl.wordpress.com/about/importing-fbx-files-into-blender-with-full-armaturesweights/) about the BOS FBX importer. I followed the instructions but nothing happens (no warning, no import, no errors... nothing) when I try and import via BOS as opposed to Blender's FBX importer.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Checking the 'automatic bone orientation' option in the import FBX options has improved the situation for a FBX file that I didn't need to convert via autodesk's FBX converter. Still, some of the bones look out of place and seem to have no function, and the scale and rotation of the model is still wrong and I can't fix it by just messing with the mesh's position values:

[image]

Comment: You can try to enable *Automatic Bone Orientation* in the *Armatures* tab.

Comment: I edited the main question.